# Global list doesn't contain value at another function

Tags: python

I want to make a global list and I saved a value in my global list (`def rand()`).

Whatever I save, my saved value doesnt include at another function except `rand()`.

What am I missing?

```
sayi = []

def rand():

    global sayi
    initial = 1000
    for i in range(1000,10000):
        initial +=1
        sayi.append(initial)
    print sayi[43]


def main():

    rand()
    print len(sayi) # Shows 0 but I have added value at rand funct. with append funct.
main()
```

Comment: Aside from the recursive call back to `main()` making this want to spin forever, this seems to work just fine for me. I get `9000` printed

Comment: Works for me too (besides the recursion causing a stack limit crash)

Comment: Also, you don't even need to say `global sayi` because you are not replacing the object itself. You are only ever accessing its attributes and modifying its values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're new to python. **INDENTATION MATTERS**. Not trying to be mean, but I've noticed that trips a lot of people up. Here's your modified code.

```
sayi = []

def rand():

    global sayi
    initial = 1000
    for i in range(1000,10000):
        initial +=1
        sayi.append(initial)
    print sayi[43]


def main():

    rand()
    print len(sayi) # Shows 0 but I have added value at rand funct. with append funct.

main()
```

you have everything working, your indentation is just a little off.

Comment: Are you only suggesting that the OP dedents the `main()`? That didn't cause the wrong value to be printed either way. It just causes a recursive loop. You still get the values.

Comment: @jdi, no I am not suggesting that the lack of indentation caused his list to have a length of zero.

Comment: Alright. I just wanted to clarify that this is actually not an answer to the OPs question. While it is good information, it is just a "side-note".